# Why Thunderbird is taking too much space

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird

This is the second time happening with me. Last time I got suggestion from a friend on same forum to use Disk Usage Analyzer to check whats consuming too space. I found out that its Thunderbird.

Same thing happening again on daily basis it is consuming more that 4GB of space I have 100GB of total space and on this rate I'll be out of space in 1 week.

More than that When i send some email its takes much time in copying the space on local repository and Gmail account.

Maximum size of email which i send is 22 to 30KB which is just text.

[image]

Comment: See [bug #1074260](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1074260).

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are using IMAP for your mail account.

You can **compress** your mail to save space.

Most likely your issue is that you have deleted items but not **purged** them which means that the messages you have deleted appear as they are gone but in fact they are still around, you will need to purge them to physically remove the items you have deleted, checkout this link for more info:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Compacting_folders